# Enabling linux-ck kernel on ArchLinux with Gummiboot

Tags: arch-linux

this is my first ArchLinux installation and I'm try to run linux-ck kernel on my ArchLinux (as a VirtualBox guest) that is using Gummiboot bootloader.
According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Repo-ck) guide, I have installed `linux-ck-ivybridge virtualbox-ck-guest-modules-ivybridge` packages, then I have added `elevator=bfq` kernel parameter to `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf` so it now looks like this:

```
# cat /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf 
title   Arch Linux
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options root=/dev/sda1 rw quiet elevator=bfq
```

Then I have run `gummiboot update`.
However, after rebbot, `uname -r` still gives me `3.12.8-1-ARCH` and `dmesg | grep scheduler` tells me that "`[    0.520294] I/O scheduler bfq not found`".

According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/linux-ck#Installation_Options), it seems that the boot loader needs to be made aware of the new kernel, however instructions for grub only are given.
I have no particular reason to keep using gummiboot instead of grub but I fear that trying to install grub now would mess my system up.
So the question is, how can I make gummiboot aware (and load) the ck kernel?
Alternatively, how can I safely replace gummiboot with grub?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution...
I had to create a new entry in `/boot/loader/entries/` to look like this:

```
title   Arch Linux CK
linux   /vmlinuz-linux-ck
initrd  /initramfs-linux-ck.img
options root=/dev/sda1 rw quiet elevator=bfq
```

and now `uname -r` reports `3.12.8-1-ck`

and `dmesg | grep scheduler` reports `BFS CPU scheduler v0.444 by Con Kolivas.`

I hope that this could help others.